# How to create image slideshow with jquery but with background-image property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, cycle

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="content_home_preview">

</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#content_home_preview{
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 940px;
height: 469px;
background-image: url("../Images/image1.png");
repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

How can I create slideshow effect with next images e.g. image2, image3, etc...

I tried jquery cycle but its form is like:

```
<div id="content_home_preview">
    <div class="image1"></div>
    <div class="image2"></div>
</div>
```

but i only need script to repeatly change background-image property with fading efect...

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, jQuery Cycle doesn't work for anything except block elements. (I don't know if it's even possible to animate transitions between background images.) Perhaps you could layer the rest of your content on top of it using CSS positioning to simulate a background image?

Comment: i thought about that, but I was about to avoid "hacking" if it is posible

Comment: I'm not really sure on how to animate the background images, but I might try to convince you to use the normal image tags; really the main reason why you would want to do this vs. using background images would be that images are accessible by screen readers (you can't specify alt tags with background images), as well as having images that relate to your content with good alt tags will only improve your SEO.

Comment: I have many divs above that div and i dont want to animate them. It would be perfect if i had script that animates background-image.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick. 
http://www.ovalpixels.com/blog/2009/02/21/making-fancy-websites-without-flash-animating-background-image/

Comment: Almost. It destroys my site but it does transition. Do you have any another useful link?

Answer (score 0):

See this instruction. Here Pure JS is used, you can use jquery using this same technique.

Reference Link - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp